# How to extract evnironment variable in docker file to pass it to use it in later stage?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to copy Java's cacerts from one image to another during mutlti-stage docker build. It goes like this

```
FROM maven__jdk18_with_certs
.... //somehow expand and store $JAVA_HOME env var
FROM someImageWhereCertsAreNeeded
.....
COPY --from=maven__jdk18_with_certs $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts /root/cacerts
```

as you can see, I have JAVA_HOME evn var that needst to be expanded and stored somehow. How can I do that?

Comment: The base image should have a fixed path where the JVM is installed; can you use that fixed path instead of relying on a (constant) environment variable?

Comment: This is what I did. But if source image will change it might break build of my images. Thats why I would like to be able to actually expand and store that.

Comment: The first stage is just a temp image. So why do you bother to put cacerts in JAVA_HOME? Why don't you put the cacerts in /my_cacerts? The temp image is deleted, so no problem if you create a new topdir called my_certs.

Comment: I dont want to copy paste content of Dockerfile for `maven__jdk18_with_certs`. I DO NOT take steps to create cacerts in the temp image in this Dockerfilre. In other words, I just need a file from different image, which happens to be potentially defined as env var in that image.